# What does *as is the case for* mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I ran into this:

> The press, and particularly the specialized travel press and the other media, including modern means of electronic communication, should issue honest and balanced information on events and situations that could influence the flow of tourists; they should also provide accurate and reliable information to the consumers of tourism services; the new communication and electronic commerce technologies should also be developed and used for this purpose; **as is the case for the media**, they should not in any way promote sex tourism.([Source](http://ethics.unwto.org/en/content/global-code-ethics-tourism-article-6))

My interpretation is that it means *just like*, that is *just like the media should not in any way promote sex tourism,  the new communication and electronic commerce technologies should not in any way promote sex tourism.*

Comment: Source? It is such a long sentence, haven't seen so many semi-colons in one sentence in awhile. As far as I can follow it I think your understanding is correct.

Comment: I guess the source is [here](http://www2.unwto.org/en/risk-crisis-management/travel-advisories).

Comment: @narengi Doesn't include the last phrase though.

Comment: @user3169 Source:http://ethics.unwto.org/en/content/global-code-ethics-tourism-article-6

Comment: This one is helpful - http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/48004/3463

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "as is the case for" is used to indicate that what has been established for the first group is also true of the second one.

For instance:

> Student athletes who compete for the school are expected to maintain a high grade point average and be regularly tested for performance-enhancing drug use, which is also the case for the chess team.